# Hats are coming

Tags: discussion, winterbash

[Winterbash 2014](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/) is on its way. It will run from  15 December 2014 to 4 January 2015.

For those who are unfamiliar with the Winterbash hat dash, it is a time of festive fun and hats. Each person can earn hats. The criteria for each hat is available at the above site, although some criteria are secret. If you earn a hat you can put it on your avatar (only one at a time). To see the sort of hats which have been available in the past, have a look at [last year's site](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/).

As with last year, if you don't want hats you can opt out.

There is also the possibility of the whole site opting out before it starts. Nobody wants that, though, right?

Comment: I'm going to just *casually* mention here that usually there is some kind of hat for pre-bash activity, usually in early December, that you won't even know if you've earned until the bash and won't have the opportunity to earn after the bash starts. Often it is connected with voting or posting on a particular day (of course we won't know which day until it is past that date).

Comment: @KitFox That's just taunting us.

Comment: Hats off to Matt for one question, two answers, two opinions. Hey, what's the question? Is it "Right?"?

Comment: Right, right? Right.

Comment: I joined in January and I'm keen to find out what all this hat business I'm hearing about everywhere is. :)

Comment: @Andrew Leach  The hats are only visible to those who earned them last year, you have to log on to view. This leaves out the newcomers.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The hats are outline-drawings and described for everyone. If you log in *and* you won a hat last year, it's there in glorious Technicolor. But even newcomers can see what sort of thing they need to achieve in order to get a hat.

Comment: So, are there multiple criteria for each hat, or only a single criterion for each? OP says  "the criteria for each hat is available"

Comment: But what about hats in 2015?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because winterbash is over.

Answer (score 31):

I want hats. Give them to me! They are my birthright!

Comment: I liked mine, I took screenshots of my avatar self last year. How sad is that?!

Comment: :D I did too! It was fun

Answer (score 8):

Hats! Let the fun (and general merriment) begin!

Answer (score 7):

I love hats! Yay! Winterbash 2014! Oh... not 'til 15 December?

Answer (score 7):

I came second site-wide last year, failing to obtain just one hat, I believe.

MOAR HATZ!

Comment: I’d take my hat off to you, were it not to alter the rankings. :)

Comment: @Ste https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/12/announcing-winter-bash-2015/

Comment: Woohoo! Hats hats hats.

Answer (score 6):

My avatar already has a hat.  Tasks which might overlay it carry a disincentive (for me, at least).

Comment: You can opt out from the hats on an individual level, so they won't affect your avatar and you won't see other people's, but the system would still be active for others and so the affects of the hat dash (a general increase in activity on the site and a bit more general silliness) would still occur.

Comment: @MattЭллен I think I detected a typical British tongue-in-cheek; stiff upper-lip old chap, droll response.

Comment: You should save yours and wear a variety of hats in the Holidays. (Your avatar can keep its, though!)

Comment: Hats can have hats.

Comment: My avatar also has a hat!  I like wearing hats on my hat.

Answer (score 3):

Hats are a sneaky and VERY FUN way of getting everyone in the "community" to get involved and maybe even do a little extra clean up of old posts, answers and comments.  I LOVE HATS! :-)

Comment: Dang!  I think I missed the boat here...

Answer (score 0):

I don't care. Hats or no hats, it makes no difference.

You ask me to choose, but I am filled with ennui even at the very mention of chosing about hats.

I could not be motivated to choose for or against even if my life depended on it.

Hat choices are meaningless.

Comment: _prolonged sigh_

Comment: superlative meh, +0

Comment: Aagh! who spoiled this superb answer by upvoting it?

Answer (score 0):

What is hats? I am not knowing this.

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/promos/2/hat-dash

Comment: Yes, I know. My post was more of a comment, but since this is meta, I wrote a meta comment for a meta question.

Answer (score -14):

Hats are stupid. You are stupid. If I see hats I'm quitting.

Comment: I agree with both of you: which do I upvote?

Comment: Upvote the one that is pro-hats. Downvote this one :D

Comment: Can we add an answer "I don't know! I really care, but I can't decide!" ?

Comment: @Mitch If you like :D

Comment: @MattЭллен: I don't know. I really care, but I can't decide.

Comment: So I’m guessing there’s a hat for having three answers in a Meta question: one with a negative score, one with a zero score, and one with a positive score?